# Just can't get CIFAR-10 convolutional network to work better than chance

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been trying to build a simple convolutional network to classify CIFAR images, and for whatever reason, I just can't it to perform better than chance. Here is the relevant bit of code (x is the cifar image data, of shape (n,32,32,3) ):

As you'll see, it's a pretty basic setup - I know it's not a very elaborate network but I just wanted to test it first before moving to more complicated architectures. However, no matter what I try, I can't get the prediction accuracy to exceed "chance guessing". When I train it, the loss steadily (more or less) declines, but gradually tapers off and saturates at the level of random guessing (i.e. 10% accuracy for CIFAR-10).

I've tried a variety of different parameters e.g. different kernel sizes, strides, different max pooling sizes, with without normalization, etc etc but it doesn't seem to budge. I just feel like I must have missed some crucial pre-processing step or something, since even a relatively simple/poorly tuned network should at least be able to manage better than chance, surely...? Thoughts, please ;-)

```
# First conv layer with max pooling
# (x is in the input CIFAR data, (n,32,32,3)
normx=tf.nn.lrn(x)
w1=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((5,5,3,depth1),stddev=0.05))
b1=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([depth1]))
act1_=tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(normx,w1,[1,1,1,1],padding='VALID')+b1)
act1=tf.nn.max_pool(act1_,[1,3,3,1],[1,2,2,1],padding='VALID')

# Second conv layer with max pooling
w2=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((5,5,depth1,depth2),stddev=0.05))
b2=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([depth2]))
act2_=tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(act1,w2,[1,1,1,1],padding='VALID')+b2)
act2=tf.nn.max_pool(act2_,[1,3,3,1],[1,2,2,1],padding='VALID')

# fully connected
d=np.prod(act2.get_shape()[1:].as_list())
wfull=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((d,nhidden),stddev=0.05))
bfull=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nhidden]))
reshaped=tf.reshape(act2,(-1,d))
actfull=tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshaped,wfull)+bfull),0.6)

# Output
wout=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((nhidden,nclasses),stddev=0.05))
bout=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nclasses]))
logits=tf.matmul(actfull,wout)+bout

loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=logits))
opt=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.2).minimize(loss)
```

Comment: How do you load the data? If you [load the data like this](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/blob/master/ML/cifar/rl/rflearn.py#L147-L156), does it work?

Comment: You should consider using [tflearn](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn) first. When you get it to work with tflearn, you can replace the tflearn functions step-by-step by pure tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the comments (sorry I just saw them!). Actually, this is going to sound strange, but it is working now and I'm not very sure what was wrong the first time! It seems to be a combination of different things (I changed to the AdamOptimizer, used a larger batch size, maybe just waited longer etc ;-) )